# Extract a number from a dynamic string

Tags: javascript, node.js

String is Dynamic.Example

```
Date18:Month5:Year1984
```

How can we extract just number 18. I cannot use substring because the values are dynamic.I want to extract only the number after Date and before :

Comment: "I cannot use substring because the values are dynamic." Well, that's patently false: `var str = "Date18:Month5:Year1984"; console.log(str.substring(4, str.indexOf(':')));`

Comment: basic regular expression

Comment: Use a regex. You can use [this website](https://regex101.com/) for assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const a = "Date18:Month5:Year1984";
const match = a.match(/^Date([0-9]+?):/);

if(match){
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: It resolved my issue.I am not familiar with Regular expressions.It really saved my time.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions are great for matching patterns. There are many ways you can write it, here is a couple ways.

```js
var str = "Date18:Month5:Year1984"

const re = /^Date(\d+):Month(\d+):Year(\d+)$/;

const match = str.match(re);

console.log(match[1], match[2], match[3]);


const re2 = /(\d+)/g;

const match2 = str.match(re2);

console.log(match2[0], match2[1], match2[2]);
```